# How to add Dropout in Keras functional model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network

Let's say I have an LSTM layer in Keras like this:

```
x = Input(shape=(input_shape), dtype='int32')

x = LSTM(128,return_sequences=True)(x)
```

Now I am trying to add Dropout to this layer using:

```
X = Dropout(0.5)
```

but this gives error, which I am assuming the above line is redefining X instead of adding Dropout to it. 
How to fix this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just add `x = Dropout(0.5)(x)` like this:

```
x = Input(shape=(input_shape), dtype='int32')
x = LSTM(128,return_sequences=True)(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
```